# How to perform k-fold CV in R?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, r-caret

I have a Python code that works well for performing k-fold CV on a dataset. My Python code looks like this:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

# Load the dataset.
dataset = pandas.read_csv('values.csv')

# Preprocessing the dataset.
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:8] 
Y = dataset.iloc[:, 8]   # The class value is the last column and is called Outcome.

# Scale all values to 0,1.
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

# 3-fold CV computation.
scores = []
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', gamma='auto')

cv = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42, shuffle=False)
for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    Y_train, Y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]

    svr_rbf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    scores.append(svr_rbf.score(X_test, Y_test))
```

Now, I want to rewrite the same thing in R, and I tried to do something like this:

```
library(base)
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)

dataset <- read_csv("values.csv", col_names=TRUE)

results <- train(Outcome~.,
                 data=dataset,
                 method="smvLinear",
                 trControl=trainControl(
                   method="cv",
                   number=3,
                   savePredictions=TRUE,
                   verboseIter=TRUE
                 ))
print(results)
print(results$pred)
```

My data is similar to this one: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/housing.data 
Except this one has 12 attributes, and 13th column is the class, in my case there are 8 attributes, and 9th one is the class. But, value-wise it is similar.

Now, I can see the results printing, however there are a few things unclear to me.

1) In my Python code, I did this scaling of values, how can I do that in R?

2) I have used SVR with `rbf` kernel, how can I use SVR with that kernel in R instead of SMV?

3) Also, in Python version I use a `random_state=42` (just a random number) to generating the splittings for the folds, so it uses different folds. But it is consistent throughout different executions. How do this in R?

4) Lastly, in Python I do the training inside a for loop per fold. I need something like this in R too, as after every fold, I want to perform some other statistics and computations. How do do this in R?

5) Should I stick to `caret` or use `mlr` package? Does `mlr` do the k-fold CV too? If yes how?

**EDIT:**

```
library(base)
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)

dataset <- read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dmpe/bfe07a29c7fc1e3a70d0522956d8e4a9/raw/7ea71f7432302bb78e58348fede926142ade6992/pima-indians-diabetes.csv", col_names=FALSE)
print(dataset)
X = dataset[, 1:8]
print(X)
Y = dataset$X9

set.seed(88)

nfolds <- 3
cvIndex <- createFolds(Y, nfolds, returnTrain = T)

fit.control <- trainControl(method="cv",
                            index=cvIndex,
                            number=nfolds,
                            classProbs=TRUE,
                            savePredictions=TRUE,
                            verboseIter=TRUE,
                            summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,
                            allowParallel=FALSE)

rfCaret <- caret::train(X, Y, method = "svmLinear", trControl = fit.control)
print(rfCaret)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `createFolds` in the `caret` package for fixed folds.

Here's some code that you can amend to fit your particular modelling case; this example would build out a randomforest model, but you can switch the model for an SVM. If you follow the package guide there's a link (copied here for ease: http://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html#support-vector-machines) - section 7.0.47 lists all the available SVM models and their parameters.Note that you may need to install some additional packages, like `kernlab`, to use specific models.

There is a package called `rngtools` that is supposed to allow you to create reproducible models across multiple cores (parallel processing), but if you want to be sure then single core is probably the best way in my experience.

```
folds <- 3
set.seed(42)
cvIndex <- createFolds(your_data, folds, returnTrain = T)

fit.control <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                            index = cvIndex,
                            number = folds,
                            classProbs = TRUE, 
                            summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                            allowParallel = FALSE)

search.grid <- expand.grid(.mtry = c(seq.int(1:sqrt(length(your_data)))+1))

rfCaret <- train(your_data_x, your_data_y, method = "rf", 
                     metric = 'ROC', ntree = 500,
                     trControl = fit.control, tuneGrid = search.grid,
)
```

In my experience, caret is pretty good for covering pretty much all bases. If you also want to preprocess your data (e.g. centre, scale) - then you want the function `preProcess` - again, details in the caret package if you type ?train - but for example you would want

```
preProcess(yourData, method = c("center", "scale"))
```

Caret is clever in that it understands if it has taken a preprocessed input, and applies the same scaling to your test data sets.

**edit - additional:  unused parameters issue**
To answer your follow up question about unused parameters - it's probably because you're using mtry which is a random forest parameter.

Here's a version for a simple SVM:

```
folds <- 3
set.seed(42)
cvIndex <- createFolds(dataset$Outcome, folds, returnTrain = T)

fit.control <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                            index = cvIndex,
                            number = folds,
                            classProbs = TRUE, 
                            summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                            allowParallel = FALSE)


SVMCaret <- train(Outcome ~ ., data = dataset, method = "svmLinear", 
                 metric = 'ROC', 
                 trControl = fit.control)
```

You don't need a tuning grid; Caret will generate a random one. Of course if you want to test specific cost values, then create one yourself in much the same way as I did for the .mtry parameter for randomForests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What's the `search.grid`'s purpose? Also, I saw `preProcess`, but it is not clear to me how to scale all the values in my dataset to 0-1 as in Python.

Comment: Also check my edited code, `cvIndex` in my case prints values between between 1 to 8, as I have that many columns, whereas I have more than 700 rows. I expected it to selects the rows as indexes, like what happens in Python.

Comment: With your SVM, you may want to play with different parameters to optimise the algorithm - e.g. the cost value. The search grid will cause caret to run multiple times for each cost value, evaluate it (e.g. against a ROC score, or Kappa, or Accuracy) - then return the scores of these models and record the best score.  The preProcess function has "rangeBounds" - so use the scale parameter and also the rangeBounds (0,1).

Comment: I don't know why it seems so complicated in R to achieve this, when Python seems to handle it easily. Give two lists which includes the list of indexes to be used for training and other list to be used for testing, and I can fit given my X and Y, and then test.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is. Caret is such a deep package that you can do everything you're trying to do with a loop pretty much from the set.seed() and then train function, and the resulting object has the detail you need. CreateFolds gives you an explicit object you can reference. The code I've added gives you huge flexibility to specify models, tune parameters such as gamma, specify the model type you want (regression vs. classification), the tuning metric (e.g. ROC/AUC, Kappa, etc.). This all comes in about 4-5 lines of code. Maybe have a play with it and see what you get out?

Comment: Check my edited code. I sent you also the dataset, so it is reproducible. Now you will run into problem that we try to do regression whereas instead I wanna do classification as my Python code. That's why I need Support Vector Machine.

Comment: I'm behind a work firewall, I can't download your data. But I would bet a simple change is all you need: change Y = dataset$X9 to Y = as.factor(dataset$X9)    You need to ensure your output variable is a factor for classification. Let me know if that works?

Comment: The error it was shown was that X is a list. But, when I do `Y = as.factor(dataset$X9)` then it gives different error, "at least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195641/discussion-between-jon-and-terett).

Answer (score 0):

1) The `caret::train` function has a preProcess argument that allows you to do choose a preprocessing. See `?caret::train` for more details.

2) There is `svmRadial` available for `caret`. You can look at examples and all available algorithms at [caret/train-models-by-tag](https://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html).

3) Fix the random seed with `set.seed(123)` for consistency. You may access training folds in the train object (`results$trainingData` here).

4) Don't loop, access your folds directly via your train object and calculate your stats if needed (see `results$resample`)

5) `mlr` has cross-validation too, it depends which flavor you like.

Comment: 4) I don't want to access the folds, instead I want to access the trained model after each fold. That's why I want to train in a loop.

Comment: first_holdout <- subset(output$pred, Resample == "Fold01")  would give you the stats for the first fold. Taken from here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114168/how-to-get-sub-training-and-sub-test-from-cross-validation-in-caret).